# Error C2039 from including MRPT library in VS2019 solution

Tags: c++, c++17, deprecated, mobile-robot-toolkit

I am implementing a SLAM-algorithm in Visual Studio 2019 where I want to use the ICP algorithm from the MRPT library for scan-matching. I have therefore downloaded and compiled the source code using CMake, and added it as an external dependency.

The code is pretty much the same as [the first example here](https://www.mrpt.org/Iterative_Closest_Point_%28ICP%29_and_other_matching_algorithms#21_Least_Square_Rigid_transformation_2Dorientation), with (I believe) all necessary headers included.

My project is written in C++17, but it seems that MRPT library is not, as I get these errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\mrpt-1.5.7\libs\opengl\include\mrpt\opengl\COpenGLScene.h(195,27): error C2039: 'bind2nd': is not a member of 'std'
C:\Program Files (x86)\mrpt-1.5.7\libs\base\include\mrpt\random\RandomGenerators.h(292,12): error C2039: 'random_shuffle': is not a member of 'std'
C:\Program Files (x86)\mrpt-1.5.7\libs\bayes\include\mrpt\bayes\CKalmanFilterCapable_impl.h(396,8): error C3861: 'bind1st': identifier not found
```

A quick search revealed that these functions `random_shuffle, bind1st, bind2nd` are removed in C++17.

Does this mean that I have to manually edit these files to work with C++17, or is there any quick fix solutions for this? For instance so that the external library is compiled with a supported version of C++ instead of C++17?

Comment: It looks like you would have to use the development version 2.0 of MRPT with c++17. But I have not been there so...

Comment: Note that the errors occur in .h files, which presumably are included in your .cpp files. Hence, they are necessarily compiled using the same C++17 compiler as your code.